# Java Finding a file in /res folder and using Scanner with it

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

My File is located in my /res, more specifically its in /res/Menus/CharSelect. I have already gone into my build path and made sure the res folder is a class path. However, my new Scanner(file) is causing a NullPointerException. 
When I do file.exists(); it returns FALSE... and I can't figure out why. I am 100% that the file does exist, and that it is located in the CharSelect folder. 
Can any one help? Thanks in advance.

```
    file = new File(getClass().getResource("/Menus/CharSelect/Unlocked.txt").getPath());
    try
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that. When you'll create a jar you won't have access to that file as a `File` object but as an [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) from which you'll have to get the `InputStream` with [`openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29).

Instead, use the [`Scanner(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream%29) with:

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResource("/Menus/CharSelect/Unlocked.txt").openStream()) {
    scanner = new Scanner(is);
    ...
} // is.close() called automatically by try-with-resource block (since Java 7)
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I would've made a jar and been confused as to why it couldn't find it. Made my life so much easier man.

Comment: @EvanNudd you're welcome :) And don't forget to close the stream (I edited my answer, we're never too cautious).

Answer (score 0):

`someClass.getResource` resolve paths relatively to `someClass` location. Move your file to PATH_TO_THIS_CLASS_PATH/Menus/CharSelect/Unlocked.txt and operation must succeed